# Create text sliding effect in carousel instead of image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to create a pure text carousel or whatever thing is that like this page first jumbotron: http://demo.rocknrolladesigns.com/html/jarvis/ .But there is no tutorial of this type of effect on the internet.Can anyone teach me how to achieve this effect and what is the name of this effect so I can gather more information?
Thanks.

Comment: I think It's just magic of Sliding Images with `up` and `down` direction - you can visit this - http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/ and http://api.jqueryui.com/slide-effect/

Comment: did you mean "WE ARE, WE lOVE" text?

Comment: @Gold-Pearl,Yes,I mean the we are coder,we love pizza

Comment: @Prog-It is not sliding images,it is text that can be highlighted

Comment: @EricWatson,try this http://richhollis.github.io/vticker/

Comment: @Gold-Pearl,is there anyway to use it without jQuery?

Comment: @EricWatson, what you like to do css or javascript?

Comment: @goldpearl,I prefer css

Comment: @GoldPearl,I am just a beginner of javaScript

Comment: @EricWatson, Javascript easier then CSS3. If you want exact output in all browser go with Jquery. Because CSS3 not supported in old browsers.

Comment: Please hold i will give you CSS3 solution.

Comment: @EricWatson, I tried lot to get this css3. but i cant, http://jsfiddle.net/h7SYp/1065/. i Ready to help you with Jquery.